# Issue with reading files from using os.getcwd() on aws ElasticBean Stalk server

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Flask/Dash application reads files `/data` directory. When I run the application locally, I use `os.getcwd()` to read the csv file.

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.getcwd() + "/data/file1.csv")
```

However, when deploying the application to AWS EB instance / server, I run into the following error.

```
File "/var/app/current/base_rent_calc.py", line 38, in <module>

Jul 24 04:53:43 ip-172-31-20-89 web: df = pd.read_csv(os.getcwd() + "/data/file1.csv")

Jul 24 04:53:43 ip-172-31-20-89 web: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How do I set the right file path / directory? or how can I check what `os.getcwd()` is on AWS ElasticBean.

Comment: You're assuming `data/` is within your current working directory.  Look at how your app is started in EB - does it specify a directory?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to connect to the Elastic Beanstalk instance, find the filepath for your 'file1.csv' file, and use an absolute path for that.

There are docs for how to connect to the EC2 instance that runs your EB instance [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.ec2connect.html). Once you've got a ssh session you'll need to fiddle around to find the file. Based off what's in your answer I would do this

```
cd /var/app/current
ls -lha
```

That will show all the files in what I'm guessing is the directory your app is running from.

Once you're in that directory too you can get a python shell and look at what os.getcwd() does by just typing python.

Comment: All the app files are in `/var/app/current` including the data folder which has the file that I am looking to read.  when I run os.getcwd(), the path is `/var/app/current'.

Comment: What happens if you type head -n 10 /var/app/current/data/file1.csv? If that gives you output of the file you want I would then replace os.getcwd() + "/data/file1.csv" with "/var/app/current/data/file1.csv".

Comment: Running `head -n 10 /var/app/current/data/file1.csv` opens the file / gives the output I am looking for. ok, I can replace `os.getcwd()`, however, don't understand why it won't work.

Comment: Does replacing it with the absolute path to the file fix the code?

Answer (score 0):

> check what os.getcwd() is on AWS ElasticBean.

This will be `/var/app/staging` when you deploy your app or `/var/app/current` when the app has been deployed.

Comment: @kms that's what I wrote. So not sure what you mean by your comment?